# How to validate name="novs[78][] using jquery validation?

Tags: php, jquery, validation

```
<?php
     for ($i=0; $i < $total_vehicles; $i++) { 
          $id=$edtVehicle[$i]->id;
          $chasis=$edtVehicle[$i]->chasis;
?>
```

//HTML CONTENT "novs[][]" want to validate it using jquery validation

```
<div class="controls content contold">
   <input type="hidden" name="hid_novs[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="text" name="novs[<?php echo $id;?>][]" id="novs_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $chasis;?>">
    <button type="button" class="removebtn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <span class="span_error"></span>
  </div>

  <?php
                        }
?>
```

JQUERY VALIDATION

```
 $("#add_user_form").validate({ 
           "novs[]":{ required:true, }, 
            messages: { "novs[]":{ required : "Please fill this value" }, }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery?

Comment: $("#add_user_form").validate({
"novs[]":{
                required:true,
            },
 messages: {
    "novs[]":{
                required : "Please fill this value"
            },
}

Comment: Update your question

Comment: Look for `jQuery validate input array`.

Comment: there not any example for associative array validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it with this way, it's solved now thank you.

```
   $("input[name^='novs_'" ).each(function(){
                $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Fill a valid value"
                }
            });   
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully this will helps you to get id

```
$('.removebtn').click(function() {
   //console.log( $(this).siblings('.removebtn'));
   //console.log($(this).siblings("input").attr('id'));
   var found = false;
     $(this).siblings("input").each(function (i, name) {
         // Check if field is empty or not
         console.log(name);
         if (!found && jQuery(name).val() == '') {
             alert('Please enter value')
             found = true;
         };
     });
     return !found;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/pga72zap/)

Comment: How does this answer the OP question?

Comment: from my code he can get the id or name then after he can validate

Comment: i want to validate it text box is empty then get validate message but here i passed name of text box is in associative array so validation fails to catch it.

Comment: Thank You, but i need with associative array.

Comment: will you give screenshot how would your from will be diplay